# How can I decompress a jsonlz4 Mozilla Firefox session file?

Tags: java, json, lz4

I'm trying to decode the `jsonlz4` file that contains my saved tabs from Firefox (saved in `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxxxx.default-release\sessionstore-backups\recovery.jsonlz4`, in the hope of eventually being able to parse the json and extract the URLs in my tabs and maybe other data from my session.

I was hoping that the `lz4-pure-java` library could decompress it to json.

I'm trying to use Method 2 Example from [the lz4-java github](https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java#examples), and [a comment here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209390#c13) says that the file should be standard lz4 if we skip the 12-byte header.

Here's my code:

```
package com.jsonparser;

import net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4Factory;
import net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4SafeDecompressor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class jsonLZ4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String infile = "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\xxxxxx.default-release\\sessionstore-backups\\recovery.jsonlz4";

        byte[] datain = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(infile));

        // need to skip the first 12 bytes for Firefox format

        byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(datain,12,datain.length);

        LZ4Factory factory = LZ4Factory.fastestInstance();

        byte[] compressed = data;
        int compressedLength = compressed.length;
        byte[] restored = new byte[compressed.length*2]; // not sure how to set length properly without knowing decompressed size

        // - method 2: when the compressed length is known (a little slower)
        // the destination buffer needs to be over-sized

        LZ4SafeDecompressor decompressor2 = factory.safeDecompressor();
        int decompressedLength2 = decompressor2.decompress(compressed, 0, compressedLength, restored, 0);

        String s = new String(restored, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("decompressed data is: " + s);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a decompression error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4Exception: Malformed input at 1803197
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4JavaUnsafeSafeDecompressor.decompress(LZ4JavaUnsafeSafeDecompressor.java:62)
    at net.jpountz.lz4.LZ4SafeDecompressor.decompress(LZ4SafeDecompressor.java:77)
    at com.jsonparser.jsonLZ4.main(jsonLZ4.java:31)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know how I can successfully decompress this file, preferably using only java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `jsonlz4` format is its own format.
It's *based* on `lz4`, but adds its own header logic.
Consequently, it's not decodable by "normal" `lz4` decoders.

If you are looking for a ready-to-use decoder source code, the `lz4` home page lists one project dedicated to this goal (though it's written in C) :

jsonlz4 decoder, custom Mozilla LZ4 format, by Avi Halachmi : https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4

For a different implementation, for example using Java, you'll be on your own. Either develop your own header decoder after reading the format's documentation, and then pass the remaining payload to `LZ4`, or try to use JNI to invoke C functions from Java.

Comment: I'm looking for a java decoder. Are you sure it's different to standard lz4? I've seen multiple people mention that it is standard lz4 except for the extra header, as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: eg https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/3offju/jsonlz4_file/cvx4a9n/ - "This file format is in fact just plain LZ4 data with a custom header (magic number [8 bytes] and uncompressed file size [4 bytes, little endian])."

Comment: We may spell it differently, but I believe we say essentially the same thing.

Comment: What I mean is that I should be able to skip the first 12 bytes and then pass the rest to a standard `lz4` decoder, but that does not work.

Comment: I think it's because the Firefox format has one big block for the full file, whereas most decoders have a maximum block size of 4Mb.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox header is 8 bytes, not 12 bytes.

As said, simply skip the 8-byte header, and decompress the compressed data stream.

Small example in Perl language:

```perl
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    use strict;
    use warnings FATAL => "all";
    use autodie;
    
    use English;
    use Fcntl qw( :seek );
    use File::Spec;
    use File::stat;
    use JSON::PP;
    
    use Compress::LZ4;
    
    if (not @ARGV)
    {
        print("$PROGRAM_NAME <file.jsonlz4>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    my $path = $ARGV[0];
    
    my $st = stat($path);
    
    open(my $fh, '<:raw', $path);
    
    # skip header
    seek($fh, 8, SEEK_SET);
    
    my $leido = read($fh, my $bytes_jsonlz4, $st->size - 8);
    die unless $leido == ($st->size - 8);
    
    close($fh);
    
    my $bytes = lz4_decompress($bytes_jsonlz4);
    
    my $perl_data = JSON::PP->new->utf8()->decode($bytes);
    my $json = JSON::PP->new->utf8->pretty->indent;

    print($json->encode($perl_data));
    
    1;
```

Comment: have you tried this on a Firefox `.jsonlz4` file, such as `recovery.jsonlz4`? Standard lz4 decoders fail because of the non-standard header. Eg see https://superuser.com/a/1363751/130337 - see the last point about lz4 blocks vs frames. I would like to be able to extract using a standard lz4 decompressor in java.

Comment: @localhost, yes, I've run the script on my profile's `.jsonlz4` files (recovery.jsonlz4, previous.jsonlz4, and bookmarkbackups). The script calls a function that deals with **raw** LZ4 data. See [link](https://metacpan.org/pod/Compress::LZ4#COMPATIBILITY). Have you tried `byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(datain,8,datain.length);`

Comment: Yes I have tried skipping the first 8 bytes (and 12 bytes). I believe it is failing because the Firefox jsonlz4 file is one giant lz4 block, but I believe the lz4-java library has a maximum block size of 4Mb. I would still like to find a java implementation that can process these stupid jsonlz4 files.